# Subtracting two numbers in sign-magnitude format

Tags: computer-science

< Assume 185 and 122 are signed 8-bit decimal integers stored in sign-magnitude format. Calculate 185 + 122. Is there overflow, underflow, or neither?

So I have that 185 = 10111001 in binary
and I have 122 = 01111010 in binary.

I'm not sure where to go from here. If it's sign-magnitude format, does 10111001 = -57 or -71?

Can I add the binaries?

If I add:

```
 10111001
 01111010
 _________
100110011
```

But this seems like it has overflow? Am I doing this right?

Answer (score 1):

Sign-Magnitude format uses the leftmost bit to represent the sign `0` meaning positive and `1` meaning negative so range of numbers we can represent with 8-bits in sign magnitude format is from `-127` to `127`.so `10111001` is -71(by taking the 2's complement and then calculating the value).

whenever there is 1 in the leftmost bit it means it is negative number and to get the magnitude of that you need to get the 2's complement of it. for more reference see this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement

and yes you can add those binaries and in addition of signed magnitude numbers if there is a carry from signed bits `ignore` it. so the result got from addition `100110011` the left most bit is carry of the signed bits so ignore it. then we have 8-bit number `00110011` and the leftmost digit is zero so it is positive number calculating its magnitude we get `51` which is exactly equal to `122+(-71)`. yes there can be cases of overflow also.more on overflow see here: https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~eedwards/compsys/arithmetic/index.html#targetText=Overflow%20Rule%20for%20addition,adding%20operands%20with%20different%20signs.

Comment: Then ask him why 122-57 is giving 51 :)

Comment: Is it possible you have sign-magnitude wrong? I thought the first bit was teh sign and the rest of it was teh magnitude. So 10111001 = -57 by that logic.

Comment: No if it is negative number then we need to take 2s complement of it to get the magnitude

Comment: @Jwan622 check on the other sources